# If $G=(V,E)$ is a planar graph, all vertex degrees are $3$, all faces are of five/six edges, how many five-edged faces are there?

Tags: graph-theory

> Given a graph $G = (V,E)$, a planar graph where every vertex has degree $3$ and all faces are five-edged or six-edged. How many five-edged faces are there?

It was a question in one of our previous exams, the answer is $12$, but I have no clue on how to solve it. I mean, I can have as many faces as I want, why is it limited to $12$ and $12$ only?

Comment: You can have as many faces as you want? Have you actually tried to come up with one with (say) $0$ five-sided faces?

Comment: if I draw a 6-edged face and given that every vertex is of degree 3, I still can and have to draw infinite 6-edged faces... I don't know. 
What's the direction to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrictions on the faces of a 3-regular planar graph](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238994/restrictions-on-the-faces-of-a-3-regular-planar-graph)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the graph is planar

$$V-E+F=2 \,.$$

As each vertex has degree $3$, by Handshaking lemma we have $2E=3V$.

Let $f_1$ be the number of $5$ edged faces and $f_2$ be the number of $6$ edges faces. Then

$$2E=5f_1+6f_2 \,.$$
$$f_1+f_2=F \,.$$

From here we get $$2E=6F-f_1 \,.$$

Thus, plugging everything in the first relation, you get:

$$\frac{2E}{3}-E+\frac{2E+f_1}{6}=2 \,.$$

Since all $E$'s cancel you are done.

Comment: I have trouble understanding how do we get $2E = 5f_1 + 6f_2$? I understand that $5f_1 + 6f_2$ is the total number of edges in those faces, but not all edges belong to two faces (some are on the outer edge of the graph), right? The other question didn't explain that either.

Comment: @VedranŠego Don't forget that the outside is also a face, is the infinite face. The formula $V-E+F=2$ counts the infinite face too.  Because of this, all edges belong to exactly $2$ faces.

Comment: ALL edges belong to two faces, don't forget that there is the infinite face.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain again how you got $2E = 5f_1 + 6f_2$ please?

Comment: @TheNotMe Count the edges by faces. You have $f_1$ faces with $5$ edges and $f_2$ faces with $6$ edged. So your count is exactly $5f_1+6f_2$. As each edge belongs to exactly 2 faces, you counted all the edges, each twice, so the count is also $2E$.

Comment: @N.S. I thought so, but messed up when counting on some example. <blush> Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for making it clearer

Comment: You are welcome.